# I'm getting API Error when I try to login after added next.js to my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, promise

I migrated and added Next.js to my React app. I getting the following error when I try to login. When I checked seems that I have to use promise.all. I tried different solutions without success. I want to know how it works. Your help and advice are highly appreciated.

error message;

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

src/action/auth.js;

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
// import { API_URL } from '../config/index';
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    SIGNUP_FAIL,
    ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
    ACTIVATION_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOADED_FAIL,
    AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
    AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS,
    PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL,
    LOGOUT
} from './types';

export const checkAuthenticated = () => async dispatch => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage.getItem('access') : false) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        const body = JSON.stringify({ token: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage.getItem('access') : false });

        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/jwt/verify/`, body, config)

            if (res.data.code !== 'token_not_valid') {
                dispatch({
                    type: AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS
                });
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL
            });
        }

    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL
        });
    }
};

export const load_user = () => async dispatch => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage.getItem('access') : false) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage.getItem('access') : false}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }; 
        
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config);
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_FAIL
            });
        }
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_FAIL
        });
    }
};

export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
            dispatch(setAlert('Authenticated successfully', 'success'));
            dispatch(load_user());
        }catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL
            });
            dispatch(setAlert('Error Authenticating', 'error'));
    }
};

export const signup = (name, email, password, re_password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password, re_password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/users/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Check Your Email to Activate Your Account.', 'warning'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: SIGNUP_FAIL
        })
    }
};

export const verify = (uid, token) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ uid, token });

    try {
        await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/users/activation/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Account Activated Successfully.', 'success'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: ACTIVATION_FAIL
        })
    }
};

//Reset Password
export const reset_password = (email) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email });
    try {
        await axios.post (`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/users/reset_password/`, body, config);
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_SUCCESS
        });
        dispatch(setAlert('Check Your Email to Rest Password.', 'warning'));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_FAIL
        });
    }
};

// Reset Password Confirm
export const reset_password_confirm = (uid, token, new_password, re_new_password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ uid, token, new_password, re_new_password });
    
    try {
        await axios.post (`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/users/reset_password_confirm/`, body, config);
        dispatch(setAlert('Password Rest Successful.', 'success'));
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SUCCESS
        });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_FAIL
        });
    }
};

//Logout
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setAlert('Logout successful.', 'success'));
    dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT
    });
};
```

src/pages/login.js;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { login } from '../actions/auth';
import styles from '../styles/Login.module.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
import WelcomePageFooter from '../components/WelcomePageFooter';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import i18n from '../../i18n';

function Login({ login, isAuthenticated }) {

  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigate = useRouter();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    login (email, password)
  };
 
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      navigate.replace('/')
    );
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div className={styles.login}>
        <Head>
          <title>Diploman - Login</title>
          <meta
            name='description'
            content='login page'
          />
        </Head>
        <h1 className={styles.login__title}>{t('login_title')}</h1>
        <p className={styles.login__lead}>{t('login_lead')}</p>
        <form className={styles.login__form} onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className={styles.login__form__group}>
            <input
              className={styles.login__form__input}
              type='email'
              placeholder={t('Form_email')}
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.login__form__group}>
            <input
              className={styles.login__form__input}
              type='password'
              placeholder={t('Form_pw')}
              name='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              minLength='8'
              required
            />
          </div>
          <Button className={styles.login__button__main} type='submit'>{t('login_title')}</Button>
        </form>
        <p className={styles.link__to__Signup}>
        {t('login_text1')} <Link href='/signup' className={styles.login__link}>{t('login_register')}</Link>
        </p>
        <p className={styles.link__to__resetPassword}>
        {t('login_text2')} <Link href='/reset-password' className={styles.reset__password__link}>{t('login_reset')}</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
      <WelcomePageFooter/>
    </main>
  )
};

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => (
  { props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(
      locale,
      ['common'],
      i18n,
    )),
  } }
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { login }) (Login);
```

I really appreciate your help here

Comment: Do not call `navigate.replace('/')` inside the component render. Move it inside a `useEffect` instead, e.g. `useEffect(() => { if (isAuthenticated) navigate.replace('/'); }, [isAuthenticated]);`.

Comment: Hi Juliomalves, Many Many thanks!!! I was far away from the solution. You ROCK! Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept and vote for you?